# How to limit template parameters to a descendent that is a specialization of a templated interface?

Tags: c++, templates, interface, template-specialization, type-traits

Assume the following situation:

1. There is a templated interface defining a set of operations on different data types.
2. This interface is implemented by various specialized classes defining the operations for actual data types.
3. There is some managing class that has to work instances of classes as defined in 2.

Simplified example code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename R, typename S>
class ICanDoIt
{
    public:
        virtual void doStuff() = 0;

    protected:
        ICanDoIt<R, S>(R rA, S sA) : r(rA), s(sA) {};
        R r;
        S s;
};

class DoesIt : public ICanDoIt<int, double>
{
        public:
            DoesIt(int iA, double dA) : ICanDoIt(iA, dA) {};

            virtual void doStuff()
                { std::cout << "r * s = " << r * s << " done." << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
class NeedsSomeoneWhoCanDoIt
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<ICanDoIt<R, S>, T>::value, 
                  "T needs to be able to do it.");

    public:
        NeedsSomeoneWhoCanDoIt(const T& doesItA) : doesIt(doesItA) {};
        void getItDone() { doesIt.doStuff(); };

    private:
        T doesIt;
};


int main()
{
    DoesIt doesIt(5, 2.2);
    NeedsSomeoneWhoCanDoIt<DoesIt> needsIt(doesIt);
    needsIt.getItDone();
}
```

If you untemplate the interface "ICanDoIt" the code will actually work. But the static_assert for the templated version will fail because ICanDoIt's template arguments are wrapped and hidden by the specialization performed in the decalaration of DoesIt.

How can I limit the managing classes (NeedsSomeoneWhoCanDoIt) template parameter "T" to *any* specialization of ICanDoIt, regardless of which type has been chosen for R, S during the specialization of ICanDoIt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always make the actual types for `R` and `S` used to instantiate `ICanDoIt` accessible to a derived class, i.e.

```
template <typename R, typename S> class ICanDoIt {
public:
  typedef R R_t;
  typedef S S_t;

  virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};
```

so that your `static_assert` would become

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<ICanDoIt<typename T::R_t, typename T::S_t>,
                              T>::value,
              "T needs to be able to do it.");
```

---

Depending on what your actual code looks like the design might become clearer if you'd define a purely abstract base class (i.e. an actual type `ICanDoItBase` instead of a template) from which you'd inherit the currently templated functionality in `ICanDoIt` which would again be a base of `DoesIt`.

`NeedsSomeoneWhoCanDoIt` could then directly use the the polymorphic base class `ICanDoItBase` without any needs for additional type checks.

Comment: @norritt: Even though it works to me your current design still feels like a weird chimera of runtime polymorphism and an overly restrictive incarnation of concepts.

Comment: Its kind of a result of the fact that there seems to be no way to manage templated class instances with different template arguments in a single container, except by using Boost (boost::any). This is part of my workaround using STL means only I'm not quite satisfied myself but thats the best thing I've come up with yet. C# style runtime type casting would make all those problems go away ;)

Comment: I'm downvoting this because in the case where `T` is *not* an `ICanDoIt`, then the compile error you will get is `no type named 'R_t' in 'struct T'`, which is pretty unhelpful. [T.C.'s solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32468830/2069064) does get you to the static assert message more clearly.

Comment: @Barry: Yes, T.C.'s solution is definitely less intrusive and altogether nicer, but I believe that a wrong `T` making the build fail is helpful already (I'd probably add a comment there).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to publish the template parameters. The standard SFINAE-based approach would work just fine.

```
namespace detail {
    template<class R, class S>
    std::true_type test(ICanDoIt<R, S>*);
    std::false_type test(...);
}

template<class T>
using can_do_it = decltype(detail::test((T*)nullptr));
```